# How to return StatusCode 401 using ASP.Net MVC5 and OWIN

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5, angular-ui-router, owin

I would like to know how to use ASP.Net MVC5, my implementation of IExceptionFilter, Microsoft.Owin and ui-router (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).

My case is: when something wrong with the permissions happens, I send a response to a client, using something like is:

```
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.Exception == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        ...

        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        filterContext.Result = "Unathorized access";
    }
```

Please note: I have set the StatusCode code to 401.

To get view templates from the server, I am using $stateProvide which requests Action methods. As you know, $stateProvide which is a core part of the ui-router can handle $stateChangeError. Unfortunately, not in my case.

I have a requirement to use Microsoft.Owin. For some reasons my response has StatusCode = 200 (NOT 401) and has "X-Responded-JSON" header:

```
X-Responded-JSON:{"status":401,"headers":{"location":"<URL>"}}
```

Here is a quote from http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.de/2013/12/returning-401-http-status-code-on.html "...The security pipeline in OWIN and MVC 5 has changed and the custom attribute was no longer returning 401 and 403 status codes. Instead it was returning a 200 status code and inserting some additional information in the header..."

Basically, it means that $stateChangeError will not be fired.

Does someone have an idea how to solve the issue?
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution was actually provided in the link which I added to my question. Here is the solution which works great for me:

```
public class StartupAuth
{
    private static bool IsAjaxRequest(IOwinRequest request)
    {
        IReadableStringCollection query = request.Query;
        if ((query != null) && (query["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest"))
        {
            return true;
        }

        IHeaderDictionary headers = request.Headers;

        return ((headers != null) && (headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest"));
    }

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnApplyRedirect = ctx =>
                {
                    if (!IsAjaxRequest(ctx.Request))
                    {
                        ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        var configuration = (IConfiguration)DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(IConfiguration));
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(configuration.FacebookAppId, configuration.FacebookAppSecret);
    }
}
```

Now I have StatusCode = 401 and the $stateChangeError is fired.

Comment: I also had to add else {
                            ctx.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                        }